# Facebook chat plugin "kills" Pagespeed - how to improve the performance of a fake button

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, facebook-chat

Like many others, I have a problem with the FB chat button on my site. The script delays loading the page a lot, and pagespeed rates the site poorly.

I found a tutorial to build a "fake button" ([Facebook chat plugin "kills" Pagespeed to 33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500211/facebook-chat-plugin-kills-pagespeed-to-33)) - so I did.

It works almost well, but from the disappearance of my "fake button" to the showing of the real one after loading the FB script passes a few seconds - too much, the user will not know what happened.

Also, how to make it so that when I click on the "fake button" the chat, after loading, behaves as if I clicked on the real button. That is, that it would display the "Login" chat window: "Continue as {user_name}" or "Continue as guest"? Now I have to click twice: the first time on the "fake button" and the second time on the "right button" after the script loads.

I looked for other solutions to this problem

Comment: Not really an answer, but I accomplished it by initializing the FB chat script after 2 - 3  seconds on the `DOM` ready state.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a button with a link to Facebook Messenger. Not every user will write to you, but everyone will notice a decrease in site speed.

Answer (score 0):

It's surely not the solution you want to read, but the best way is to remove the Facebook chat plugin. It's a real disaster on PSI.